# Appendable with a capacity limit

Tags: java

I would like a class which implements Appendable, writes into an in-memory string (i.e. StringBuilder or StringWriter), but imposes a hard limit on the maximum capacity.

I did not find something similar in the Java standard library, nor in any 'commons' library, such as Guava or Apache Commons.

I specifically need the Appendable interface implementation, since this is a requirement of a 3rd party library which I use.

Answer (score 0):

Delegate the string collecting internally to a StringBuilder field.

```
public class A implements Appendable {
    private final StringBuilder sb;
    private final int max;

    public A(int max) {
        this.max = max;
        sb = new StringBuilder(max);
    }

    @Override
    public A append​(char c) {
        if (sb.length() < max) {
            sb.append(c);
        }
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public A append​(CharSequence csq) {
        return append(csq, 0, csq.length());
    }

    @Override
    public A append​(CharSequence csq, int start, int end) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Maybe you were hindered by StringBuilder being a final class, non-extendable.

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted to avoid - implementing it myself. I do not like inventing wheels.

Comment: Rereading the question I now understand. "Is there an existing class ..." might have been more clear. The only class that fits (I know of) is [**`CharBuffer`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/CharBuffer.html). Its usage however is not made for an unproblematic API.